# Web crawler: web content does not show up in html code

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am doing a basic web crawler work for this web page (just for study purpose, and I have got their permission):

http://www.seattle.gov/council/calendar#/?i=0

What I wanted to do is to get all the events' "Time", "Description" and "Location" in that form. I have tried python regular expression however it looks like these information does not show up in the HTML code of this page. Instead, I am using a Selenium, but I still don't know where to find this information.

Comment: They provide **RSS feed**. See: http://www.trumba.com/calendars/seattle-city-council.rss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, things are in front of you but you don't see them.

You can fetch/extract that data from their **RSS Feed**. It's here: http://www.trumba.com/calendars/seattle-city-council.rss

Hope this helps.

Comment: I never thought about this option! Thank you so much! It cost me the whole afternoon...

Comment: My pleasure @Emile